# How to calculate cartesian product of iterable objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to calculate cartesian product in EcmaScript 6

---

Example :

```
product([["I", "They"], ["watch", "drink"], ["the sea", "the juice"]])
```

Expected result :

```
[["I", "watch", "the sea"], ["I", "watch", "the juice"], ["I", "drink", "the sea"], ["I", "drink", "the juice"], ["They", "watch", "the sea"], ["They", "watch", "the juice"], ["They", "drink", "the sea"], ["They", "drink", "the juice"]]
```

---

Example :

```
product([[-1, -2], [10, 20]])
```

Expected result :

```
[[-1, 10], [-1, 20], [-2, 10], [-2, 20]]
```

Comment: What is purpose of nested `for..of` loops if `arr2` is not and element of `arr1`?

Comment: Cartesian product !

Comment: Thought, it's more a challenge, than something really useful !

Comment: Given example `javascript` at Question, and none of nested loops appearing to depend on property or value from preceding `for..loop`, not certain what expected result is?

Comment: The goal is to get a cartesian product = all the possibilities when you combine the arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “pretend JavaScript is Haskell” version:

```
const re = g => a => ({
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => g(a)
})

const cons = x => re(function* (xs) {
  yield x
  yield* xs
})

const map = f => re(function* (xs) {
  for (const x of xs)
    yield f(x)
})

const ap = fs => re(function* (xs) {
  for (const f of fs)
    for (const x of xs)
      yield f(x)
})

const product = ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x ? ap(map(cons)(x))(product(xs)) :
      [[]]
```

Use as follows (well, don’t, actually):

```
for (const l of product([arr1, arr2, arr3]))
  callback(...l)
```

`re` makes a pure generator reusable.

Comment: Thank you ! Very interesting !

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ryan's idea :

```
let flatten = arr => [].concat(...arr);

function product([x, ...xs]) {
    if(!x) return [[]];

    let next = product(xs);

    return flatten(x.map(a =>
        next.map(b => [a, ...b])
    ));
}
```